# Java connection String ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm

Tags: java, oracle, encryption, jdbc, oracle11g

I have problem connecting Oracle cloud database from my connection string, the error says:

> ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm

I tried my connection string with other oracle databases, all works, except for this cloud db.

I also tried solution like this the following, but not works (changed parameters in `sqlnet.ora`)

https://doganay.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/ora-12650-no-common-encryption-or-data-integrity-algorithm/

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<hostname>:1521:<SID>";
try {
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "username", "password");
} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("Database access failed " + e);
}
```

Comment: [This](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3565179?start=0&tstart=0#12462300) could help (seems that you need to set some properties for the driver)

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure correct version of Driver jar being used, to avoid this kind of issues